# How to use original_exception of InternalServerError

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, werkzeug

according to [werkzeug docs](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/exceptions/#werkzeug.exceptions.InternalServerError), `InternalServerError` has `original_exception` parameter. That looks cool and I'would like to use it in following way to handle exceptions:

```py
@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def handle_errors(err):
    return err if isinstance(err, HTTPException) else InternalServerError(original_exception=err)
```

and log it in `@app.after_request` method to pack all additional info from `request` and `response`, where standard request logging occurs. Unfortunatelly I'm not able to find out how to use stored `original_exception`. Where is it stored?

When I check `sys.exc_info()` in `@app.after_request`, it's also empty (or `(None, None, None)`).

One way is probably log exceptions directly in `@app.errorhandler`, `request` info should be accessible there and `response` is not ready (because of error) anyways, but what happens with `original_exception` after storing in `InternalServerError`???

Thanks for answer, Michal

Answer (score 0):

I found myself here looking for the same thing - how to access the `original_exception`, but I eventually gave up and settled on [traceback](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html) to give me the info I was seeking.

This is the key component, capturing the traceback stack as a list:

```py
formatted_lines = traceback.format_exc().splitlines()
```

Here's my final code in which I extracted the line number of the error and the specific trigger, then passed them to the page:

```py
from werkzeug.exceptions import InternalServerError
import traceback

@app.errorhandler(InternalServerError)
def handle_500(e):
    templateData = {
        'errorAt' : 'Internal Server Error',
        'errorIs' : 'Check ~/www/gunicorn.error for details'
    }
    try:
        formatted_lines = traceback.format_exc().splitlines()
        for error_location in formatted_lines:
            if 'intvlm8r.py' in error_location:
                templateData['errorAt'] = error_location
        templateData['errorIs'] = formatted_lines[-1]
    except Exception as e:
        app.logger.debug(f'handle_500: Unhandled exception: {e}')
    return render_template('500_generic.html', **templateData)
```